# Problem rendering search results in search component React, Semantic-UI-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to use the custom render for a search box. I am using semantic-ui-react.

Following is a code snippet for the render method :

```
  render() {
    const { isLoading, value, results } = this.state

    const resultRenderer = ({ clientName }) => (
            <div>               
                <p>{clientName}</p>               
            </div>
        );

    resultRenderer.propTypes = {
        clientName: PropTypes.string
    }

    return (     
          <Search            
            loading={isLoading}
            onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
            onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 10, {loading: true})}
            results={this.state.results}
            value={value}
            resultRenderer={this.resultRenderer}
            {...this.props}
          />                      
    )
  }
}
```

The code snippet below is the handleSearchChange method :

```
handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {

    var resultsArray = []
     this.setState({ isLoading: true, value })

                api.autoCompleteClient(value).then(res => {

                var tempArray = res.data.data.hits.hits
                var autoResult = []


                for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
                {

                    resultsArray.push(tempArray[i]._source.clientName)
                }


                }).catch(error => {

                console.log('Some error got while performing autocomplete for clients ', error)
                })


    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.value.length < 1) return this.setState(initialState)
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        results: resultsArray,
      })
    }, 300)
  }
```

The results in the render when printed can be seen in the following screenshot :

[image]

However, the results in the search bar are empty and I am getting the following errors as can be seen below :

[image]

Inside the result renderer if I put a print statement, I get the following results :

[image]

Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have a typo in row 6: you probably meant to have `<clientName/>` (not `</clientName>`.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy thanks! I edited my post to correct the typo. But that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is the culprit:

`resultsArray.push(tempArray[i]._source.clientName)`

Not sure what your data looks like, but if you have three empty results and there are three results, I'm guessing it's not grabbing the right property.

It looks like you need to set the state in the .then() callback for api.autoCompleteClient. This way you know the data is ready, instead of just waiting for 300ms.

I also suggest using Array.map() instead of the for loop for brevity/showing intent.

And just a heads up, using the React Devtools extension in Chrome lets you examine the state/props of components in real-time.

As for the first first two console warnings, I would just look in SemanticUI docs and see what the props are for that component, it looks like two aren't actually used.

The last warning just meaning you need a key prop when mapping multiple components, to help render them more efficiently. So just key={someUniqueValue}.

Edit: Try this :)

```
const resultRenderer = (data) => {
  debugger;
  return (
        <div>               
            <p>{data.clientName}</p>               
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I do get the correct value for results in the render method, so I think the state is getting updated correctly. The number of search results is 3 as can be seen by the 3 search suggestions in the screenshot. It's just that it isn't rendering the results correctly.

Comment: @sublime_archon Just updated answer, without data it's hard to tell, but try debugging results renderer !

Comment: just updated my question to show the results from the result renderer! Could you please check it out? Thanks!

Comment: @sublime_archon I think it's from changing type from String to Object which is what semnaticui-react is expecting. According to semanticui-react docs it's expecting data in the form of:   "results": [
    {
      "title": "Schinner - Tillman",
      "description": "Object-based system-worthy framework",
      "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jffgrdnr/128.jpg",
      "price": "$13.97"
    },

Comment: Not "results: ["string1", "string2"]" which is converted into {0: 's', 1: 't', 2: 'r', etc. }

Comment: Thanks adamz4008! So should I be converting every result into an object first?

Comment: Hey @adamz4008, converting every result into an object before pushing it into the resultsArray did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

can you also paste your code in search component?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with help from @adamz4008.

The updated code for handleSearchChange with the corrections looks as follows:

```
handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {

    var resultsArray = []
     this.setState({ isLoading: true, value })

                api.autoCompleteClient(value).then(res => {

                var tempArray = res.data.data.hits.hits
                var autoResult = []

                for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
                {
                    //Converted every result into an object
                    //Semantic React UI renders objects 

                    var result = {clientName : tempArray[i]._source.clientName}
                    resultsArray.push(result)
                }

                }).catch(error => {

                console.log('Some error got while performing autocomplete for clients ', error)
                })


    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.value.length < 1) return this.setState(initialState)

      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        results: resultsArray,
      })
    }, 300)
  }
```

Also the result renderer looks as follows after correction :

```
const resultRenderer = (data) => {
    console.log('Inside resultRenderer ', data)
    return (
        <div>               
            <p>{data.clientName}</p>               
        </div>
    );
    }
```